# How can i hash username in Laravel

Tags: laravel, hash, passwords

I use Laravel Authentication and want to hash all user data .
How can i hash username in Laravel and decode in login page like password ?

I edited Register controller like this

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => bcrypt($data['username']),
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to hash all your user data? If you're asking a question about how to do it, then you likely haven't considered why it is necessary in the first place and whether its actually a good idea. The reality is, if you get breached to get your database, its not far to assume they could breach your project too. If that is the case they'll get your app_key and therefore the ability to decrypt your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes hash is 1 way process but you can use encryption for same type of process.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

$encrypted = Crypt::encryptString('Hello world.');

$decrypted = Crypt::decryptString($encrypted);
```

non-PHP clients receiving encrypted values will need to unserialize the data. If you would like to encrypt and decrypt values without serialization, you may use the encryptString and decryptString methods of the Crypt facade.

so always use Crypt Facade because all thing work in background automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Hash is different from encoding/decoding. Hash is a one-way process, whereas decoding/encoding is a two-way process.

For Hash, once something is hashed you can not get the original any more, however, if you use the same value and hash again you will get the same hash result.

For decode/encode, you can get the original value back.

In `Laravel` by default, the password is hashed not encrypted or encoded.

So, hash a username is a bad idea. You will never know what's the username once it's been hashed.